# My programme enteres a blank row before entering data to CSV file how to delete the row or stop it from adding the row?

Tags: python, csv

This is my code and when I enter the programme and try to find the records and get them sorted it shows up list index out of range and when I take the quiz it shows up everything all right but when I enter the CSV file there is an empty row between the input and the beginning of the file I tried deleting the empty rows and the programme works sorts the data and prints it but with the empty rows it just shows up the error mentioned above.

```
a=True
b=True
c=True
import random                                   #Here i imported a random module
import csv
import operator
score=0                                 #I made a variable called score and set it to 0
menu1=input("What do you want to do? Take Quiz(t) See Scores(s) ")
if menu1 == ("s"):
    menu2=input("How do you want it sorted? alpabetically(a) acording to score highest to lowest(s) or according to average score highest to lowest(a) ")
    if menu2 == ("a"):
        menu3=input("Which class are you in a b or c ")
        if menu3 == ("a"):
            sample = open("ClassA.csv","r")
            csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter=",")
            sort=sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(0))
            for eachline in sort:
                print(eachline)
        if menu3 == ("b"):
            sample = open("ClassB.csv","r")
            csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter=",")
            sort=sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(0))
            for eachline in sort:
                print(eachline)
            menu4=input("Do you want to take the quiz now? ")
            if menu4 == ("no"):
                print("Thank you for Looking At the scores!")
            if menu4 == ("yes"):
                menu1=input("What do you want to do? Take Quiz(t) See Scores(s) ")


elif menu1 == ("t"):
    while a == True:                          #Opens a loop called a
        name=input("What is your name? ")       #I asked the user their name here if name == (""):
        if name.isdigit() or name == (""):       #If the user enters a number or nothing something will happen
            print("Incorrect Name")          #This is the message that appears when the the name is a number or is nothing is incorrect
        else:
            a=False                              #Here i closed a loop
            print("Welcome To my quiz " +str(name))#This is the welcoming message
            while b ==  True:
                group=input("What Class Are you A,B,C ") #Asks The User their class
                if group == ("a") or group == ("b") or group == ("c") or group == ("A") or group == ("B") or group == ("C"):
                    break
                else:
                    print("No such class!")



def addition():                            #Here i define a function called addition
    score=0                              #Here the score shows score
    first_number_a=random.randint(1,10)         #The program gets a random number
    second_number_a=random.randint(1,10)                  #The program gets another random number
    question1=int(input("What is " +str(first_number_a)+ "+" +str(second_number_a)+ " "))                #Here the program asks the user a question
    total_a=(first_number_a+second_number_a)                         #The answer to the question above
    if question1 == total_a:                  #If answer is equal to the new variable c which is the answer to the question
        print("Correct!")               #This tells the user they got it correct
        score=score+1                   #This adds a point to the score
    else:                               # if answer is not the variable
        print("Incorrect!")             #Here the program will print that the user is incorrect
        print(total_a)                        #Here the program prints the correct answer if they got the question wrong
    return score         #This keeps the score safe


def multiplication():
    score=0
    first_number_m=random.randint(1,10)
    second_number_m=random.randint(1,10)
    question2=int(input("What is " +str(first_number_m)+ "*" +str(second_number_m)+ " "))

    total_m=(first_number_m*second_number_m)
    if question2 == total_m:
        print("Correct!")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        print(total_m)
    return score

def subtraction():
    score=0
    first_number_s=random.randint(1,10)
    second_number_s=random.randint(1,10)
    question3=int(input("What is " +str(first_number_s)+ "-" +str(second_number_s)+ " "))
    total_s=(first_number_s-second_number_s)
    if question3 == total_s:
        print("Correct!")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        print(total_s)
    return score

qw=["a" , "b" , "c"]              #List Of Letters that will be randomly selected to then start a function
for i in range(0,10):            #Thsi willrepeat the process listed below however many times in this example 10 times
    random_Letter=random.choice(qw)     #Selets a random letter   
    if random_Letter == "a":                #If the random letter is a
       score += addition()              #It will use the function addition
    elif random_Letter == "b":
       score += multiplication()
    elif random_Letter == "c":
       score += subtraction()
print("your score is " +str(score)+ " Out of 10")#Tells the user their final score
if group == ("a") or group == ("A"):            # If users input is as specified
    f=open("ClassA.csv","a")#This opens a file
    c = csv.writer(f)
    c.writerow([name,score])  #Writes To A file
    f.close()                       #This closes the file saving anything the user wrote to it
elif group == ("b") or group == ("B"):
    f=open("ClassB.csv","a")
    c = csv.writer(f)
    c.writerow([name,score])
    f.close()
elif group == ("c") or group == ("C"):
    f=open("ClassC.csv","a")
    f.write(name)
    f.write(str(score)+ "\n")
    f.close()
```

Comment: There's a lot going on there, but you probably need to configure your CSV writer like this: `c = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')`.  Also you don't appear to be using `CSV` for `ClassC`, is this intentional?  Which file is producing the blank line?

Comment: The class a is producing the blank row but the class c is intentional as I am only checking out if this solution works

Comment: No this line doesn't work

Comment: I changed the file to text and now it works thanks anyway